# Get Serializable ArrayList on Intent fragment

Tags: android, android-intent, kotlin, fragment

On my fragment I want to get `ArrayList<Animal>`. I have created a newInstance function.

```
  companion object {
    private val ARG_TITLE = "ARG_TITLE"
    private val ARG_ANIMALS = "ARG_ANIMALS"

    fun newInstance(title: String,animals: ArrayList<Animal>): ExampleFragment{
        val fragment = ExampleFragment()
        val args = Bundle()
        args.putString(ARG_TITLE, title)
        args.putSerializable(ARG_ANIMALS, animals)
        fragment.arguments = args
        return fragment
    }
}
```

And on my `onCreate()` I have this.

```
 private var title: String = ""
lateinit private var animals:ArrayList<Animal>

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    if (arguments != null) {
        title = arguments.getString(ARG_TITLE)
        animals = arguments.getSerializable(ARG_ANIMALS)
    }
}
```

But

> Required: ArrayList  found Serialized!

Can't cast to ArrayList neither.

Comment: Did you try casting it to `(ArrayList<Animal>)`?

Comment: Yes,         animals = arguments.getSerializable(ARG_ANIMALS) as ArrayList<Animal>

Comment: make sure animal class has implemented Serializeable

Comment: What line is the error on?

Comment: I think args.putSerializable(ARG_ANIMALS, animals as Serializable) should work!

Answer (score 32, accepted):

As mentioned in a comment, cast it:

<sub>NOTE: casting to Serializable isn't necessary if it's an **ArrayList** (this means `ArrayList` - List and MutableList are affected differently). `List` and `MutableList` has to be cast to Serializable (otherwise it shows an "incompatible types" error)</sub>

```
args.putSerializable(ARG_ANIMALS, animals as Serializable) //This is to cast it to the appropriate form in order for it to be serialized properly
```

and mirror it on output:

<sub>Casting here is necessary no matter what. Otherwise you'll just get a Serializable and not the class which you have serialized.</sub>

```
animals = arguments.getSerializable(ARG_ANIMALS) as ArrayList<Animal>
```

Type has to be specified in the diamond, otherwise you get an error as a result of `animals: ArrayList<Animal>` not matching `ArrayList<*>`

You may want to look into using List instead of ArrayList though, to generalize which types you accept (include MutableList for an instance).

And this only works if Animal implements Serializable. Otherwise it'll crash when you put/get the list from the bundle. Lists are only serializable if the class in them are too.

Comment: Could you explain a bit more why is it necessary to cast `animals` to `Serializable` when passing it to `putSerializable`?

Comment: @SpaceBison tbh, when I did testing I used List and MutableList. It is apparently not necessary with ArrayList, but with List and MutableList it has to be cast to Serializable.

Comment: I see. That would be because`ArrayList` implements `Serializable`, but `List` and `MutableList` do not extend it, so they need an explicit cast. :)

Comment: They can still be serialized though, assuming the class it holds is serializable. But that appears to be right :)

Answer (score 1):

Get ArrayList on intent fragment is done with this line of code.
And this code work for both Serializable and non-Serializable ArrayList of Object type.

```
//first add this dependency in app build.gradle file
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'


//to send the arraylist contains elements of object type.
ArrayList<Object> mOrderList=new ArrayList();
//suppose this list now contains some data like number of objects.
Fragment fragment new YourFragment();
Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
Gson gson = new Gson();
String jsonDetails = gson.toJson(mOrderList);
bundle.putString(IntentKeyConstants.TAG_ORDER_LIST, jsonDetails);
fragment.setArguments(bundle);
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction=getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.main_frame, fragment, CURRENT_TAG);
fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(CURRENT_TAG);
fragmentTransaction.commit();


//to get the arraylist contains the element of object type in fragment
ArrayList<Object> mOrderList=new ArrayList();
Gson gson=new Gson();
String jsonDetails;  
jsonDetails=getArguments().getString(IntentKeyConstants.TAG_ORDER_LIST);
Type type=new TypeToken<ArrayList<SuggestionResponseBean>>(){}.getType();
mOrderList=gson.fromJson(jsonDetails,type);
```

I hope this solution will help you.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try casting argument which you get in fragment into arraylist which you wanted:
Most probably this would work for you:

eg.

```
"ARRAYLIST_OBJECT"= arguments.getSerializable("ARGUMENT_NAME") as ArrayList<"ARRAYLIST_NAME">
```

Thank you.

Comment: You cant use a string as a type argument, nor can you cast in this way, nor can you use 'as' like this.

Comment: " " This is an example which indicates that you have to write the object here. Please be clear about it. Its literary specified ARRAYLIST_OBJECT please read the answers carefully.

Comment: "Its literary specified ARRAYLIST_OBJECT" means absolutely nothing and there is no reason for you to write it as a string - but even if he corrected the strings, that code is nonsense - It is meaningless even as pseudocode. The only thing this answer could ever achieve is to waste the time of people new to java who would be lost by this.

Comment: Please post other idea if you have, we would learn from it :)  no egos.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make your Animal class implements **Serializable** and use below code to set data in the bundle

```
args.putSerializable(ARG_ANIMALS, animals)
```

In order to get the data in another fragment as below

```
animals = arguments.getSerializable(ARG_ANIMALS)
```